# Firebase Cloud Messaging with Google client library

Tags: c#, google-api, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm currently trying to migrate an existing server-side application which uses Firebase Cloud Messaging. To my understanding, [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.FirebaseCloudMessaging.v1) NuGet package is suitable for that; I have successfully referenced it in the existing C# project.

However, the documentation available [here](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.FirebaseCloudMessaging.v1/latest/api/Google.Apis.FirebaseCloudMessaging.v1.html) is indeed a very documented, but does not give a step-by-step example on how to initiate a call. How can I formulate a call to the API? I have done so in the past successuflly with a customized HTTP request, but don't understand how to do this with the API.

Has anyone successully used this API before and could give some insights? Although I use C#, any experience already made with a different language will be appreciated.

Comment: wrong library try this one https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet

Comment: Hi @DaImTo thanks for the hint, but please be more specific. From a brief look at https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/index.html, Firebase Cloud Messaging does not seem to be supported by this library.

Comment: Checking but i really though everything cloud based was in the cloud library.   Either way i dont think there is much documentation for it.   You may have to dig around in the code and create your own working example.

Comment: What about the code here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#c

Comment: Apparently there is an alpha in the works https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis